# Dropping external table in spark is dropping the location or data too

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hive

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{Path,FileSystem}
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SaveMode, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{current_date, from_unixtime, unix_timestamp}
import spark.implicits._
    spark.sql("drop table if exists Staging.test_partiton_drop")
    val df = Seq(("Aravind", "DIP"), ("Karthik", "DTP")).toDF("name", "dept")
      .withColumn("hdp_load_dt", current_date()).withColumn("hdp_load_hr", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), "HH"))
    var partitionBySeq = Seq("hdp_load_dt", "hdp_load_hr")
    df
      .write.partitionBy(partitionBySeq:_*)
      .format("parquet")
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .option("path", "/krnoir/streaming_test")
      .option("compression", "snappy")
      .saveAsTable("Staging.test_partiton_drop")

    val fs = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
    val finalPath = new Path("/krnoir/streaming_test/_REPLICATION.DONE")
    fs.create(finalPath,false)
```

When I ran the above code, /krnoir/streaming_test/ is getting overwritten in each run while I am expecting new files to be added and not overwritten.

Comment: `saveAsTable` isn't making an external table